# I'm getting the error clear missing intents when coding a bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client({ ws: { intents: new Discord.Intents(Discord.Intents.ALL) } });
```

this is a code that requires all intents is it wrong

```
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Coleria is online!');
});

const prefix = '*'
```

can I go with this prefix

```
client.on("message", message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ");
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'sa'){
        messageCreate.channel.send('As kardeşim hoşgeldin.');
    }
});

client.login("my token");
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't to use `ws: { intents: new Discord.Intents(Discord.Intents.ALL)}`

```
const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
  ]
});
```

You should use this code because your bot is trying to find the `GUILDS` and `GUILD_MESSAGES` flags, and that's all you need to use.

Comment: my bot need to do moderation it will work?

Comment: yes it'll work anyway, i'm using it on my client.